# ASP.NET Core Web API Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm a tad confused - I've created an ASP.NET Core Web API MVC Project but when i try to make a request i am getting the following response:

I am posting to https://localhost:44337/api/Solve with Postman the following body:

```
{
    "examId":"0f537776-1acf-478f-82ee-c8476bc3e005",
    "selectedAnswers":
    [
        {
            "id":"9163fd1c-ec0f-4f1f-8ead-05ffeac36426",
            "answerText":"Yes",
            "isCorrect":true

        },
        {
            "id":"00545a13-212b-46a5-9d06-3f6abbb9f1d8",
            "answerText":"Yes",
            "isCorrect":true
        }
    ]
}
```

and receive this as a response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "8000005f-0001-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I've already included the Content-Type.
GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.ApiRoute = "api/" GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.PostSolve = "Solve"
Here is my controller:

```
    [Route(GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.ApiRoute)]
    [ApiController]
    public class ESchoolController : ControllerBase
    {
        protected IApiService ApiService { get; set; }

        public ESchoolController(IApiService apiService)
        {
            this.ApiService = apiService;
        }

        //POST: api/Solve
        [HttpPost]
        [Route(GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.PostSolve)]
        public IActionResult Solve([FromBody]ExamApiSolveInputModel model)
        {
            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return this.BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                var result = this.ApiService.SolveExam(model, userId);
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return this.BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my input models:

```
    public class ExamApiSolveInputModel
    {
        public ExamApiSolveInputModel()
        {
            this.SelectedAnswers = new List<AnswerApiInputModel>();
        }

        public string ExamId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AnswerApiInputModel> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerApiInputModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string AnswerText { get; set; }

        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    }
```

I've been searching for solution, but unsuccessfully. I've tried some things like:

1. When i make request it's not entering the controller. I've checked
   it with the debugger.
2. Making another post method but again it's not entering the code via
   debugger, so I think the problem isn't in the code.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks alot and happy holidays!

Comment: 400 is invalid request. Without [MCVE] showing how you make the request no one will be able to help.

Comment: What would you want to know?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov when i try with empty controller it also says 400 invalid request

Comment: Either your ApiService is throwing an exception, or `User.FindFirstValue` is. Its probably the ApiService. Can you post that class, or at least the methods used in `SolveExam`? I've copy and pasted your models and controller into a new project and commented out the `ApiService` and `User` references and I am getting 200 OK. One of those is throwing an exception. Use your debugger to step through a request and see where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Josh it cannot break in the controller, it's just skipping it

Comment: .Net Core 2.1 and higher automatically return an HTTP 400 when `ModelState` is invalid. It's the `ModelStateInvalid` which is an action filter; it won't go into the controller method. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.modelstateinvalidfilter?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Try disabling that action filter and then inspect your `ModelState` for errors: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/disable-automatic-model-state-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

Comment: @ValentinTrifonov change public ICollection<AnswerApiInputModel> SelectedAnswers { get; set; } to public IEnumerable<AnswerApiInputModel> SelectedAnswers { get; set; } or array and remove constructor and check

Comment: I've tried all the things you said but again it's not working...

Comment: I created new project and it works, but in the main project is not working. How is it possible?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `services.AddMvc(options => services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));` from the **Startup.cs** file and the problem disappeared!

Comment: If you want to keep that for Mvc requests but not ApiController requests you can use the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information how do you make your request.

Make sure you do include your JSON in body and set `Content-Type` header as `"application/json"`

Comment: what values do you have in these constants: GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.ApiRoute and GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.PostSolve ?

Comment: GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.ApiRoute = "api/"
GlobalConstants.RouteConstants.PostSolve = "Solve"

Comment: something else going on there. I created test core 3.0 api using code you provided and making post request using postman and json from example, works like a charm.